# Can't find href attribute

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to selenium.

I am trying to get Selenium to see the following link on a page

```
<div>Microblog: <a href="/index">Home</a></div>
```

However no matter what I try I can't get selenium to find it. 
the current test I have is:

```
class TestMod2HomeClick(unittest.TestCase):
    # test setup
    def setUp(self):
        self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
        self.display.start()
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    # test
    def test_validate_click_home(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/mod2")
        # find the home line
        home_link = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('##')
        for link in links:
            print home_link.get_attribute("href")
```

the following error get thrown https://gist.github.com/Naughtron/846f30efe95f826a1116

so my question is how do I find the home link and click it?

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following line:

```
home_link = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('##')
```

with

```
home_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('home')
```

More info here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text

EDIT: please note that this will return one element or throw `NoSuchElementException`. So you shouldn't iterate through the results, it doesn't make sense.